# Quarkus Application PublishToMavenLocal not working

Tags: maven, gradle, quarkus

I'm trying to publish a Quarkus application to MavenLocal but I don't see any files in my `.m2/repository` folder.
I've added the **maven-publish** plugin to my **build.gradle** file and I'm not getting any errors when publishing.
Maybe I've missed something and need to do more configuration to publish it ?
Here is my build.gradle file and my gradle.properties file :

```yaml
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson'
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}

group 'org.acme'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

test {
    systemProperty "java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
}
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

```
#Gradle properties
#Sat Jan 13 11:02:39 CET 2024
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-bom
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus.platform
quarkusPlatformVersion=3.6.5
quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
quarkusPluginVersion=3.6.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `maven-publish` plugin is not configured properly.
By enabling detailed log like `./gradlew --info publishToMavenLocal` no related task(s) will be found.

To enable publishing just add the following section to `build.gradle`

```groovy
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

***NOTE #1***

There are many options to customize publication. For further information see [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)'s guide.

***NOTE #2***

In Gradle 8.5 the `:generateMetadataFileForMavenJavaPublication` task will fail due to enfordec platform spec.

To disable this check just add the following snippet to `build.gradle`

```groovy
tasks.withType(GenerateModuleMetadata).configureEach {
    suppressedValidationErrors.add('enforced-platform')
}
```